# Trouble installing gevent on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, gevent

I have been having trouble installing gevent on Mac OS X Mavericks.  I am trying to install into a virtual environment.  First I installed libevent with brew.  Then I ran:

```
pip install gevent
```

Unfortunately, I could not get it installed because I kept getting this error message:

```
Command /Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/traffic/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/traffic/build/greenlet/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/yv/vnky4wpd7kl4bp4qb4hlqmhw0000gn/T/pip-91tw1E-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/traffic/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/traffic/build/greenlet
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/christopherspears/.pip/pip.log
```

The issue seems to be with greenlet.  Has anyone else com across this error?

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of /Users/christopherspears/.pip/pip.log?